# Using the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathbb{F}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. If $f$ is measurable, let $E_n = \{x \in X: (n-1) \leq |f(x)| < n\}$. Show that $f$ is integrable if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\mu(E_n) < \infty$.

I proved the above using the monotonicity of the integral. However, is there a way to prove this using the monotone convergence theorem? I feel like you should be able but I do not see it.

EDIT

I just realized I did not use the fact that the space has finite measure. How does that fact play a role?

Comment: Could you please clarify *why* you would like to use MCT for this?

Comment: Because I was thinking about it, and was wondering. I know it is not necessary, as with monotonicity and finiteness of the measure space you can do it as well, like you showed. But I am trying to fully grasp the MCT, and wanted to see how it would play out for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f= f^+-f_-$ we can assume that $f$ is nonegative.

Assume that $\sum_n n\mu(E_n) <\infty$. Let $ f_n = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x) \chi_{E_i}(x)$. Then $f_n \le f_{n+1}$ and $f_n \to f$ and each $f_n$ is measurable.  Due to the monotone convergence thm $\lim_n \int f_n d\mu \to \int f d\mu$. It is clear that $f\le \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \chi_{E_i}(x):=g(x) $ and so $$\int fd\mu\le \int g d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \mu(E_i)<\infty$$
due to definition of the integral. ($g$ is the limit of an increasing sequence of simple functions).

Now assume that $f$ is integrable. Then, due to the finiteness of the measure $f+1$ is also integrable. But $g\le f +1$, hence $$ \sum_{n} n\mu(E_n) = \int gd\mu \le \int (f +1)d\mu < \infty.$$

Comment: Thanks! now I see where the MCT could be used.

Comment: @funmath Then how exactly is MCT used here?... In the answer it is only stated that $f_n\uparrow f$ allows us to conclude that $\int f_n\uparrow\int f$ on base of MCT. But so what? Nowhere in the rest of the proof I can find any application of that fact. Wouldn't the proof also have worked if the fact was just left out?...

Answer (score 1):

Observe that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)1_{E_n}\leq |f|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n1_{E_n}$$Taking the integral on both sides leads to:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mu(E_n)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)\mu(E_n)\leq\int |f|\;d\mu\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mu(E_n)$$where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)=\mu(X)<\infty$.

This shows that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mu(E_n)<\infty\iff\int |f|\;d\mu<\infty$$

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful because my approach was similar but with an error. Now I understand where we need finite measure space. Edit: just giving @Mick the green mark because he addressed the MCT but your answer helped me a lot as well.